# Chat generated from comment thread disappears

Tags: support, bug

I moved a comment thread to chat and later closed the browser tab by accident. Going back to chat in a new tab, that room seems to have disappeared.
There seems to be this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/311988/18157 but it was closed as not reproducible.

Curiously, I located the chat room via the original comment thread, and after that the thread started appearing on the chat interface.  However I can't tell if that's because of what I did or because the other user posted a commend in the interim.

In either case I think there's a heisenbug at play here.